# Dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: Connection reset by peer

Tags: logging, dovecot

I've got these messages inside my mail.log from dovecot:

```
Feb 13 07:06:49 xxx dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: Connection reset by peer
```

What do they mean?

Answer (score 2):

Change in dovecot that introduced this is http://dovecot.org/list/dovecot-cvs/2011-November/019388.html

On a server I look after these all seem to match up with postfix losing its connection to the auth server. We have it setup through lmtp. Example log line is

`postfix/smtpd[32407]: warning: unknown[1.2.3.4]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server`

I've yet to see any legit clients fail with this, it has all been people trying to brute force accounts.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me. (Especially the link)
It is of course idiotic if postfix print a message that doesn't say anything, they should have set in it which "request pending" was and which client has disconnected and how. But this is only my private message.